# .toDataURL() is saving transparent image instead of actual image

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

`toDataURL()` is saving the **black overlay/background**, that is drawn on canvas; but not the image is drawn on the same canvas through a link. If I only draw an image and try to save it as an image, the transparent image is saved.

I have researched many things but nothing worked in my case.

[Image link](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xta1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/10372115_851622004879914_7833333574997982223_n.jpg?oh=d2d0805552c2ba9365660ba28731d9f0&oe=57F70AEC&__gda__=1477014978_08b04c9b05ec32ad5122bf747e5ef066)

I have attached an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IJid.png) for better understanding...

**Here is the code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
    $user=$_POST['h'];
    ?>

    <canvas id="can" width=250 height=250 ></canvas>

     <script type="text/javascript">

        //first canvas
        var c = document.getElementById('can');
         c.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous');
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d",{preserveDrawingBuffer: true});

        var img = new Image();
         img.addEventListener("load", function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        }, false);
        img.src = '<?php echo $user ?>';

        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);

        var sent = convertToImg(c);
        document.body.appendChild(sent);
        console.log(sent);

        function convertToImg(imgc) {

            var img = new Image;
            img.src = imgc.toDataURL("image/png");
            return img;

        }


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: toDataURL function to get a data: url that has the base-64 encoded image. Note that the image must be fully loaded, or you'll just get back an empty (black, transparent) image.

Comment: that is why i added an event listener... Is it ok? otherwise suggest me some other technique... Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

the loading of image is async, you can get the source after loading completed.

BTW, you can use canvas.toDataURL directly.